# Is it safe to uninstall everything associated with MySql?

Tags: php, mysql, uninstallation

I've started learning php recently and will be using MySql. But I have a lot of MySql 'things' installed on my computer (in the screenshot). I want to completely uninstall everything and have XAMPP handle whatever is needed. I want to know would it be a good practice to do so and is it actually safe to remove everything, making sure that nothing would break and is there a way to check if some software depends on any of those?

[image: uninstaller]

Comment: We have no idea what software you might have installed that depends on them so we've no way of knowing if it is safe to remove them.

Comment: @Quentin , yeah I forgot to add that in the question but had in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Version is very old, so update it urgently.

You **only need** the Server and the shell.

Workbench is helpful as it provides a gui, even when phpmyadmin doesn't work.

If you decide to use Java c++ or other languages you can always come back and install them again. Them same goes for samples and Documentation

Comment: will XAMPP cover the Server and the shell?

Comment: Xampp brings his own MySql Server and so a separate Installation is not needed and can cause problems as you need two different ports for it, but it also bings only the server shell and documentation